# Fine-tuning distilbert takes hours

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am fine tuning the distilbert pretrained model for sentiment analysis (multilabel with 6 labels) using Huggingface emotion dataset. I am new to this, but 1 epoch, 250 steps takes around 2 hours to train on Google Colab notebook, is this normal? The train dataset has 16.000 twitter text data which of course affects the performance but isn't this too long? What is the reason behind this?

Also after 3 epochs, the accuracy started to drop. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using a GPU? If not, it's normal that it would take this much time. Also, I wouldn't be bothered by the accuracy if you're not able to run it for more epochs.

Comment: I thought I was using gpu because I chose cuda but turns out I have to select it from colab too. Thanks a lot now it's 2 minutes. It is amazing that it could have such a drastic change though.